# How to make a textfield for searching data from Database?

Tags: java, swing, documentlistener

I am trying to develop a Java application that runs on Windows.  For part of the application, I want to allow the user to enter a date into a text field in a form.  My application will use that date to query a MSAccess database to retrieve information which will be placed in other elements of the form.

How should I retrieve the information from the database using a document listener?

[I have tried searching for advice, but have not found what I need.]

Comment: My dear friend, i think my question isnt clear for you. I havent asked about connecting to a database. I have just asked about autofinding data from the database when we type in a textfield. I know documentlistener helps in achieving that, if you know about it please help.

Comment: Yes, your question is rather unclear. So what would you want to use a DocumentListener for, to update the results as the user is typing? In that case, simply implement the appropriate listener methods and either fire a new query or preferably filter the data in memory each time the textfield is changed. There are many examples of DocumentListeners in general, so just get started and ask a _specific_ question when you run into problems.

Comment: The entering of a Date is not the type of data you would do an incremental search on. That is you need to enter the entire date before it makes any sense. So, I doubt you would use a DocumentListener. I would probably add a "Search" button to the form. Then when the date is entered in the text field you would search the database.

Comment: @camickr - i have added a search button according to your suggestion.
Its retrieving the data too, but what should be the specified condition to retrieve data only from that date? i'll edit the question with the code i am using.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a decorator for a text field that display matching results as the user types. I think that is what you want if I am not mistaken. Here is the link https://github.com/Skylion007/java-manga-reader/blob/master/src/org/skylion/mangareader/util/AutoSuggestor.java